# Android Listview - Get item focused

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, android-relativelayout

I have a `listview` that contains a dynamic number of items. I am trying to get the focused item in order to position an `imageView` accordingly.

Here is an example where positioning works on buttons:

[image]

```
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final ImageView arrow = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.arrow);
    final ImageView arrow1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.arrow_1);


      button1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlParams;
            rlParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    (int)RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (int)RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            rlParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, R.id.Button1);
            rlParams.setMargins(0,0,0,5);
            arrow.setLayoutParams(rlParams);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlParams1;
            rlParams1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    (int)RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (int)RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            rlParams1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, R.id.Button1);
            rlParams1.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,R.id.Button1);
            rlParams1.setMargins(10,0,0,5);

            arrow1.setLayoutParams(rlParams1);


        }
    });
```

and same for the other buttons.

The problem is that with method I have to specify the id of the view, as in this line:

```
rlParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, R.id.Button1);
```

So my question is, how can I do this on the `listview` items? as I don't have an id for each item.

Comment: Why not implement those arrows directly in the row layout?

Comment: @Luksprog the arrows are outside the item. If I can make it look outside that would solve it.

Comment: But if you scroll the list than the arrows move with the row, right? Anyway, I don't see how do you expect your approach to work, you're trying to mix views from different containers which will not work. You can make the row to contain the arrow and show them on demand.

Comment: I thought maybe the listview creates an id for each item that can be used with the approach i demonstrated. Now I'm going to try with your suggestion. But a question, how can I get the focused item from inside the adapter? If I try to set the focus listener on the convertview it doesn't work. 
thank you for your help!

Comment: What exactly do you understand by focus?

Comment: So far I'm not finding the difference between 'focused' and 'selected'. Note that the device I'm using does not support touch.
If I want to set a focus listener, shouldn't it be on the convertView inside the adapter? Isn't that the view of each item in the listview?

Comment: @Luksprog I was able to call the view in list.SetOnItemSelectedListener. What I'm not figuring out, is how to control the view (of an item) after selection (what I need is to change the visibility of the imageView (arrow). Do you know how can I achieve this?